# Adding cookie values

Tags: javascript, html

I have site that sells items. I have created the cookies having a

- title,
- price,
- quantity
- total

I have an add to basket button which stores the cookie and i have a view basket button which links to another html page which onload reads the cookies for each product. Each product has an individual total but what i would like to do is add the totals together for an overall total. I do not know how to write a function to get the cookie total values.

Thanks

Comment: never rely on commercial information stored on the client (cookies, javascript, querystring, etc) without double checking it on your server.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

I know that the javascript purists will kill me for this, but you should really think about using a jQuery Plugin like this one:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

It will make your life much easier.

This page:

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/working-with-cookies-using-jquery-and-javascript/

shows you how to access cookies with both javascript and a jQuery plugin.

Comment: then i'd check out jbabey's link above